# jQuery not working with code here

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Show and Hide" id="_showhide">
    <span id="textsh">hide</span>
    <div id="contentsShowHide" style="display:none;">
        Contents here
    <div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function headerShowHide(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#_showhide').click(function(){
        $('#contentsShowHide').toggle(function(){$("#textsh").text("show")},function(){$("#textsh").text("hide")});
      });
});}
```

`<div id="contentsShowHide">` is not showing or hiding, and the text is not changing for 
 `<span id="textsh">`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you ever call `headerShowHide`? Take `$(document).ready()` out of the function and see if that works.

Comment: yes, i do. and it is `<scrip>`headerShowHide();`</script>`. Thank you

Comment: `<scrip>`?  Is that a typo or is that the actual tag you use?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);">click here</a>, do you forget to close the anchor tag?

Comment: Similarly, does your actual code contain `funtion` rather than `function` or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: I added jquery code in a file .js with name is "home.js", and then i added it to html file with `<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/home.js"></script>` and then i call function in file "home.js" is "headerShowHide();" with code `<scrip>headerShowHide();</script>`. Thank you.

Comment: @aaa You still haven't answered my question, which is quite relevant; is `<scrip>` a typo or not?  This is the second time you've posted it.

Comment: @pkachhia: it is a error in quesion here, it isn't in my project. Thank you

Comment: @Daedalus: `<scrip>` is a typo in question here. Thank you

Comment: @aaa And finally, please respond to icktoofay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/fad3M/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#_showhide').toggle(function(){
    $("#textsh").text("show");
            $("#contentsShowHide").hide();
}, function(){
                $("#textsh").text("hide"); 
                    $("#contentsShowHide").show();
});
});
```

Comment: @aaa If this answer solves your problem, please accept it.  You can accept it by clicking the outlined checkmark under the down arrow.  Accepting an answer not only gifts you and the answerer with reputation, but it lets others know the question has been answered, if they are looking for a similar problem.

Comment: But contents as begin it not hidden.

Comment: @pragnesh chauhan: i want to content show only when i click on `<a>`, and hide when i click next to it again. But with your code demo, i edit file html of `<div id='contentsShowHide'>` to `<div id='contentsShowHide' style="display:none;"`, it done. But when i click to `<a>` times second. But i want to `<div>` show times first when i click to `<a>`. Thanks

Comment: @aaa, i am not getting you point, can you please explain, and in html `</a>` is not ended

Comment: @PragneshChauhan: Can you see it here: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vuongmaopro/fad3M/)**

Comment: there is my problem. Do you help me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18271/discussion-between-pragnesh-chauhan-and-aaa)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#_showhide').click(function(){
        $('#contentsShowHide').toggle(function(){
            $("#textsh").html("show")},function(){
                $("#textsh").html("hide");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

there is no need for calling headerShowHide().

Comment: Your edit has not fixed the error, and the error was not indentation-related.

Comment: @Daedalus - If you know the error, consider fixing with an [edit] on the user's behalf. You *do* have full editing privileges after all. ;) This isn't a contest, we can (and should) all help to create great answers! This also demonstrates to new users how editing -- which is at the heart of SE -- can turn so-so answers into great ones. Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 :/ So be it.  I had thought it would be better for them to spot it themselves.

Comment: @sujathan, for the error I fixed, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12967489/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#_showhide').click(function(){   
    if ($('#contentsShowHide').is(":visible"))
    {
      $('#contentsShowHide').hide();
      $("#textsh").text("show");
    }
    else
    {
      $('#contentsShowHide').show();
      $("#textsh").text("hide");
    }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLeDA/). simple approch